# Why does the clothes deform when using rigify and changing the pose?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, rigify

I used rigify to create a rig for my character, and then added the clothes by parenting to empty vertex groups and transferring vertex data with a modifier. When I try to change the pose in *Pose Mode*, the clothes have a really bad fit. By comparing to youtubers who use the same method, the fit shouldn't be **that** bad. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

[image: The character after changing the pose slightly]

Here is a link to the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iB5xTK615zqUQ4EHIlGPec-da7jKCLDR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you apply the Data Trasnfer it will work better, not sure why though...

Comment: Thanks that works much better!

Comment: Maybe you should mask the skin with a Mask modifier?